# Winsock - read integer from Java client in C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, types, winsock

I have a client-server application, with the server part written in C++ (Winsock) and the client part in Java.

When sending data from the client, I first send its length followed by the actual data. For sending the length, this is the code:

```
clientSender.print(text.length());
```

where `clientSender` is of type `PrintWriter`.

On the server side, the code that reads this is

```
int iDataLength;
if(recv(client, (char *)&iDataLength, sizeof(iDataLength), 0) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    //do something
```

I tried printing the value of `iDataLength` within the `if` and it always turns out to be some random large integer. If I change `iDataLength`'s type to `char`, I get the correct value. However, the actual value could well exceed a `char`'s capacity.

What is the correct way to read an integer passed over a socket in C++ ?

Comment: SImple explanation - use a protocol with an unambiguous byte-by-byte representation so that endianness, alignment, delivery etc. are irrelevant and it will always work.

Comment: I think you are trying to cast a text representation of the number directly to an `int`. Maybe read it into a char buffer then use something like `std::stoi()`. Here s what a `PrintWriter` does to your `int`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28int%29 *"The string produced by String.valueOf(int) is translated into bytes"*.

Comment: You need to convert it to network endian from platform endian. Then you need to make sure any data you send has the same size on the other side. There you convert back to platform endian. It's no as easy as it seems. Better use a text protocol like JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that PrintWriter is writing **text** and you are trying to read a **binary number**.

Here is what PrintWriter does with the integer it sends:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28int%29

> Prints an integer. The string produced by String.valueOf(int) is
>   translated into bytes according to the platform's default character
>   encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the
>   write(int) method.

Try something like this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cstring> // for std::strerror()

// ... stuff

char buf[1024]; // buffer to receive text
int len;

if((len = recv(client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) == -1)
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::string s(buf, len);

int iDataLength = std::stoi(s); // convert text back to integer

// use iDataLength here (after sanity checks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the endianness is not the issue? (Maybe Java encodes it as big endian and you read it as little endian).

Besides, you might need to implement `receivall` function (similar to `sendall` - as [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sendall)). To make sure you receive exact number of bytes specified - because `recv` may receive fewer bytes than it was told to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a confusion between numeric values and their ASCII representation.

When in Java you write `clientSender.print(text.length());` you are actually writing an ascii string - if length is `15`, you will send characters `1` (code ASCII `0x31`) and `5` (code ASCII `0x35`)

So you must either :

- send a binary length in a portable way (in C or C++ you have `hton` and  `ntoh`, but unsure in Java)
- add a separator (newline) after the textual length from Java side and decode that in C++ :

  ```
  char buffer[1024]; // a size big enough to read the packet
  int iDataLength, l;
  l = recv(client, (char *)&iDataLength, sizeof(iDataLength), 0);
  if (l != SOCKET_ERROR) {
      buffer[l] = 0;
      iDataLength = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &iDataLength);
      char *ptr = strchr(buffer, '\n');
      if (ptr == NULL) {
           // should never happen : peer does not respect protocol
           ...
      }
      ptr += 1; // ptr now points after the length
      //do something
  }
  ```

  Java part should be : `clientSender.println(text.length());`

EDIT :

From Remy Lebeau's comment, *There is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads in TCP. recv() can and does return arbitrary amounts of data, so you cannot assume that a single recv() will read the entire line of text.*

Above code should not do a simple `recv` but be ready to concatenate multiple reads to find the separator (left as exercise for the reader :-) )

Comment: There is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads in TCP. `recv()` can and does return arbitrary amounts of data, so you cannot assume that a single `recv()` will read the entire line of text. You must buffer all received data, searching the buffer each time until you find your delimiter, then process the buffer up to that delimiter, remove what you have processed from the buffer, and repeat as needed until the delimiter is no longer found in the buffer, then keep any incomplete data in the buffer so it can be completed and processed later when more data arrives.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : of course you are right and above code is over simpified. But for something such simple I was too lazy to explicitely implement manual buffering, and thought that using a `fdopen` to later use `fgets` or `fscanf` could confuse OP. With your comment it now more clear :-)

Comment: I ended doing something that's a combination of what you suggested and @galik's suggestion of using `std::stoi()`. The length is preceded and succeeded by a delimiting character (`char`). I'm using only `recv` though.